# Calling a C# dll from C++ using CoCreateInstance

Tags: c#, c++, com, comvisible

My **ProjectA** a `C#` class library with one single class :

```
  namespace myLib
  {
    // Interface declaration.
    [Guid("Some GUID")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface ICsClass
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        int Add(int Number1, int Number2);
    };

    [Guid("Some GUID")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("myLib.CsClas")]       
    public class CsClas : ICsClass
    {
         public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked `Register for com interop` using `VS2010` which generated `dll` & `tlb` files for me, Ok until now.

My **ProjectB** a `Win32 Dll` application with single `cpp` file:

```
    #import "MyLib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
    using namespace MyLib;
```

...............

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) long Add(int a,int b)
    {
        CoInitialize(NULL); 
        long lResult = 0;       
        // Use Smart pointer
        CComQIPtr <ICsClass> spCoClass;
        if (SUCCEEDED (spCoClass.CoCreateInstance(L"myLib.CsClas")))
        {
            spCoClass->Add(a,b,&lResult);   
            wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);
            std::cout << "#"+lResult << '\n'; 
        }
        CoUninitialize();
        return lResult;
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

.......

Iam able to compile this Dll and everything looks ok until now.

Question when I use my Win32 Dll & try calling the Add function
this line :

```
 SUCCEEDED (spCoClass.CoCreateInstance(L"myLib.CsClas"))
```

Never gets passed, What might be the issue, Didnt it resgistered properly?

Kindly assist.

Comment: What hresult do you get back from CoCreateInstance?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @MatthewWatson : No error message at all.

Comment: @doctorlove : Which `hresult` ?

Comment: @user1042031 He means the return value from CoCreateInstance()

Comment: @doctorlove : Ohh sorry The result is 0x800401540

Answer (score 2):

The code as written doesn't give you a good way to diagnose the failure.  Write it like this instead:

```
    HRESULT hr = spCoClass.CoCreateInstance(L"myLib.CsClas");
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
       // etc..
    }
```

A common error code is 0x80040154, "Class not registered".  Etcetera.

Comment: Yes, I got the same error : `0x80040154`... But I can see my GUID in registry ?

Comment: I got it,I have to build and register com for 64 Bit as my calling Dll is 64Bit one.